# Click event won't fire inside button when wrapped inside a tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I wrapped my table rows in `a` tag and the button `@click` functionality won't work properly and it opens the link from `a` tag.

I want to open a popup menu when buttons click only and when user clicked in rows it should redirect it. I mean clicking the buttons should not fire redirection

code:

```
<nuxt-link
  style="color: #212121"
  v-for="item in customers"
  :key="item.userId"
  :to="'/customer/profile/?id=' + item.userId + '&name=' + item.name"
  role="row"
>
              <div role="cell">
                {{ item.name }}
              </div>
               <div role="cell">
                <v-btn
                  @click.stop="deleteItem(item)"
                  fab
                  x-small
                  text
                  class="ml-2"
                  color="danger"
                  v-if="
                    $store.state.role === 'manager' ||
                      $store.state.role === 'developer'
                  "
                >
                  <v-icon color="danger">
                    mdi-delete
                  </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  @click.stop="editItem(item.userId)"
                  fab
                  x-small
                  color="primary"
                  class="ml-2"
                >
                  <v-icon color="white">
                    mdi-pencil
                  </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </div>
 </nuxt-link>
```

I created a table using `div` tag and `display: table` CSS tags and wrapped each row with `nuxt-link` to create an anchor

Comment: have you tried chaining the event modifiers? `@click.stop.prevent="deleteItem(item)"`

Comment: @Chin.Udara Thanks. it's the trick I was looking for. it fixed!